# "Reached maximum number of custom objects" while creating BigObject

Tags: custom-object, workbench, big-object

I am trying to create a Big Object through workbench but I keep hitting the following error message:

> reached maximum number of custom objects.

I have only used 6% of my custom object allocation so I have no idea why this is the case. 
Has anyone encountered something similar?